# How to edit 3D plots to include labels?

Tags: plotting, legending

In this simple example, I want something like as shown in the figure (which I did in paint)
[image]

where  $\sin(xy)$ and $\cos(xy)$ are shown on surfaces rather than separately as legends.

```
 Plot3D[{Sin[ x y], Cos[x y]}, {x, 0, \[Pi]}, {y, 0, \[Pi]}, 
 Mesh -> None, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

Comment: Other alternatives are `PlotLabels -> "Expressions"` or `Plot3D[{Callout@Sin[x y], Callout@Cos[x y]}, {x, 0, Pi}, {y, 0, Pi},
 Mesh -> None]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this acceptable or are you looking for something smarter?

```
Plot3D[{Sin[x y], Cos[x y]}, {x, 0, \[Pi]}, {y, 0, \[Pi]}, 
 Mesh -> None, 
 PlotLegends -> {Placed["Cos(xy)", {0.27, 0.55}], 
   Placed["Sin(xy)", {0.49, 0.57}]}]
```

[image]

In case you also want the `PlotLegends` on the side as well, the following works - though not very elegant.

```
a = Plot3D[{Sin[x y], Cos[x y]}, {x, 0, \[Pi]}, {y, 0, \[Pi]}, 
   Mesh -> None, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"];
b = Plot3D[{Sin[x y], Cos[x y]}, {x, 0, \[Pi]}, {y, 0, \[Pi]}, 
   Mesh -> None, 
   PlotLegends -> {Placed["Cos(xy)", {0.27, 0.55}], 
     Placed["Sin(xy)", {0.49, 0.57}]}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"];
Show[a, b]
```

[image]

Comment: It looks good. Yeah, I do want to through away Legends! Thanks.

Comment: Glad I was able to help